# pass parameter html to javascript

Tags: javascript, html

how to pass parameter from html to javascript, i have code like below

```
<asp:Button ID="Button2" OnClientClick = "createPopupWin('webform5.aspx?alamat=+<%=TextBox5.Text %>+','Google Map', 1200, 650);" runat="server" Text="Map" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  function createPopupWin(pageURL, pageTitle,
                          popupWinWidth, popupWinHeight) {
    var left = (screen.width - popupWinWidth) / 2;
    var top = (screen.height - popupWinHeight) / 4;
                                                 
    var myWindow = window.open(pageURL, pageTitle,
                               'resizable=yes, width=' + popupWinWidth
                               + ', height=' + popupWinHeight + ', top='
                               + top + ', left=' + left);
    }
</script>
```

thats code doesn't work, variable TextBox5.Text can't get in other page (WebForm5.aspx)

Comment: javascript on the client side cannot access objects using their server-side name, unless you set "ClientIDMode" = Static on the object.  Otherwise, look at how you can use <% TextBox5.ClientID %> to access the client-side object name - which would allow you to reference - for example - document.getElementById('<%=TextBox5.ClientID %>').value, which will be the actual contents of the client-side text-box, at the time of running your javascript script

Comment: Note: "ClientIDMode" = Static may not be an available property, depending on which .Net Framework version you are targeting.  Therefore, if you don't have "ClientIDMode" = Static available to you, you will have to use the TextBox5.ClientID approach